# How to authenticate hosted wcf service with username and password?

Tags: .net, wcf

I have hosted a wcf service in an server which runs fine in that server. I try to add a service reference of that service which also added successfully in another server and then try to authenticate these service like below

```
var engServiceClient = new EngServiceClient();
engServiceClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Anonymous;
engServiceClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = @"test";
engServiceClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = @"hello";
engServiceClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = @"123wcf";
var getData = engServiceClient.GetActiveEngagements();
```

but I got exception **An error (The request was aborted: The request was canceled.) occurred while transmitting data over the HTTP channel.**

Configuration File generated after adding the service reference

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="EngService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://testwebdemo-t.orioninc.com:8443/Services/2012v2/EngService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="EngService"
                contract="ServiceReference1.IEngService" name="EngService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

How can i authenticate this service by using my username and password?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, while setting up WCF services/clients it's very useful to configure WCF tracing to get more detailed and user friendly error messages. For more info about WCF tracing please refer to [WCF Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx)

What kind of client authorization are you trying to implement? I can see you specified `Windows` type for transport security and `UserName` for message security which is both redundant and confusing.

Suppose you just want a simple username and password authorization not Windows one over https. Then your security section should look like this:

```
<security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" establishSecurityContext="true"/>
      </security>
```

Then you can use this code to specify your credentials on the client side.

```
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";
```

Hope it helps